# Remove function for an array list, failing to meet spec's

Tags: python

I am currently trying to write a remove method for an ArrayList.
I have commented out my code's methodology below. Could someone please explain to me why this code is failing when being tested? Precisely, when run, the console will give me an error with "raise ValueError()" in the last line.

```
    def __delitem__(self, idx):
                if idx != len(self)-1:
                    raise ValueError('Can only delete last item in constrained list!')
                super().__delitem__(idx)
           
         #DELETES THE FIRST REQUESTED ELEMENT FOUND FROM THE LIST 
            
        def remove(self, value):
                """Removes the first (closest to the front) instance of value from the
                list. Raises a ValueError if value is not found in the list."""
                
                truthValue = 0 #initialized a false truth value to begin with. 
                
                for a in range(0, len(self.data)-1): #A for loop to traverse the list 
                    if self.data[a] == value: #Is this the requested value? 
                        
                        self.__delitem__(a) #If so, delete it. 
                        truthValue = truthValue + 1 #Put truth value to "True"; it was found
                        break  #break out now we deleted. 
                
                if truthValue == 0: #This means it was not found, throws a value error. 
                    raise ValueError()
  from unittest import TestCase
import random

tc = TestCase()
lst = ArrayList()
data = []

  
    for _ in range(25):
        to_rem = data[random.randrange(len(data))]
        data.remove(to_rem)
        lst.remove(to_rem)
        
    tc.assertEqual(data, lst.data._as_list())
    
    with tc.assertRaises(ValueError):
        lst.remove(9999)
```

Comment: What does `self.__delitem__` look like? And what class is this in? Are you sure `self.data` is being initialized in the constructor?

Comment: Technically you are iterating one time too few, so you'll miss the last element

Comment: Also worth mentioning that between the use of the term "ArrayList" (which is not a thing in Python), the old-style index-based range for loop, and the liberal use of exceptions, all of this smells like it's being taught by a Java programmer who doesn't know Python. If you're getting this coding style from a tutorial, I might suggest seeking out a different tutorial.

Comment: Off-topic, but it's more self-documenting to use `True` and `False` for your `truthValue` variable.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo I added my delete method above. As for classes, it is in a class called Contrained Class, which has been given limited functionality. Does that help you find an issue?

Comment: @enzo, thanks! Made that edit.

Comment: You never actually delete anything from `self.data`. You just call `super().__delitem__`, which, assuming this class inherits from `object`, is an error.

Comment: If you are sure that it's the last line where you're seeing the `ValueError` being raise from, then the only ways this might happen is (a) the `for` loop is never entered or (b) the `self.data[a] == value` is never evaluated to be `True` for all values of `a`.

That said, without knowing what `self.data` looks like or knowing for sure, that the `ValueError` you're seeing is the same one that the code raises, it is hard to infer what's going on.

Comment: @lonetwin I found and added the test code that is failing. Does that help you? Sorry, I am just learning Python so I am thinking that it would be that self.data from the test code which would be causing an error. I have been staring at this for a while now and cannot put my finger on it.